# flutter firebase_database joining two nodes

Tags: firebase, plugins, firebase-realtime-database, dart, flutter

Typically you can use a map function in javascript to update the data coming back. I can not seem to find a method to allow for this in Dart Streams.

Example
https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/10/queries-part-1-common-sql-queries.html

```
var fb = new Firebase("https://examples-sql-queries.firebaseio.com/");
fb.child('user/123').once('value', function(userSnap) {
   fb.child('media/123').once('value', function(mediaSnap) {
       // extend function: https://gist.github.com/katowulf/6598238
       console.log( extend({}, userSnap.val(), mediaSnap.val()) );
   });
});
```

I was trying this using the flutter firebase_database.

```
  var _fireFollower =FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference()
      .child('followers/' + auth.currentUser.uid);
  _fireFollower.onValue.map((snap){
    print(snap.snapshot.key);
  });
```

However the map function never gets called so I cannot join any other data when it gets fetched from Firebase.

Also the end of this what I am trying to use is a FirebaseAnimatedList, so how can I pass a Query if I don't do a map??

```
new FirebaseAnimatedList(
query: _fireFollower,
  sort: (a, b) => b.key.compareTo(a.key),
  padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  reverse: false,
  itemBuilder: (_, DataSnapshot snapshot,
    Animation<double> animation) {
    return new Activity(
     snapshot: snapshot, animation: animation);
    },
    ),
```

Answer (score 1):

In Flutter, `DatabaseReference.onValue` is a `Stream`, so you have to call [`Stream.listen`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-async/Stream/listen.html) on it and cancel your `StreamSubscription` when you're done listening. If you just want to get one value event, you should instead call `once()` to get a `Future` representing the snapshot value. When it completes, you'll have your snapshot.

```
Future.wait([fb.child('media/123').once(), fb.child('user/123').once()])
  .then((snapshots) => print("Snapshots are ${snapshots[0]} ${snapshots[1]}"));
```

This can be even simpler if you do it in an `async` function because you can just call `await` to get the result of `once()`:

```
print("Snapshots are ${await ref1.once()} ${await ref2.once()}");
```

Comment: Dart and Flutter are both new to me, but I think something is wrong with the plugin for firebase_database.

I added more to this in the github for the plugin [https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/10321](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/10321)

It seems to me that I should be able to manipulate the Stream `onValue` by using a map function.

Comment: Updated question how to use with the FirebaseAnimatedList. @collin-jackson

Comment: You can use a FutureBuilder to read the data you want and ensure that it's available at the time you build your list. Consider just using a regular ListView if you don't need it to update automatically when the data changes. Or you can have the individual listview items do more querying using FutureBuilder.

Comment: @CollinJackson Why do you return a `new FutureBuilder` instead of simply returning a card?  Also, what's the difference in the FutureBuilder DataSnapshot and the FirebaseAnimatedList DataSnapShot?

Comment: You need to use a `FutureBuilder` or `StreamBuilder` whenever you are reading the contents of the database, because the values aren't available synchronously. `AsyncSnapshot` is used by `FutureBuilder` and `StreamBuilder` to provide values asynchronously, and it can wrap a `DataSnapshot` which represents the key and value of a database entry.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the suggested solution by @collin-jackson, here is my code...

```
 return new Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Flexible(
                      child: new FirebaseAnimatedList(
                        query: FirebaseDatabase.instance
                                .reference()
                                .child('followers/${auth.currentUser.uid}'),
                        sort: (a, b) => b.key.compareTo(a.key),
                        padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        reverse: false,
                        itemBuilder: (_, DataSnapshot followerSnap,
                            Animation<double> animation) {
                          return new FutureBuilder<DataSnapshot>(
                            future: FirebaseDatabase.instance
                                .reference()
                                .child('users/${followerSnap.key}')
                                .once(),
                            builder: (BuildContext context,
                                AsyncSnapshot<DataSnapshot> userSnap) {
                              switch (userSnap.connectionState) {
                                case ConnectionState.none:
                                  return new Text('Loading...');
                                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                                  return new Text('Awaiting result...');
                                default:
                                  if (userSnap.hasError)
                                    return new Text(
                                        'Error: ${userSnap.error}');
                                  else
                                    return new User(snapshot: userSnap.data, animation: animation);
                              }
                            },
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ]);
```

Class for User

```
@override
class User extends StatelessWidget {
  User({this.snapshot, this.animation});
  final DataSnapshot snapshot;
  final Animation animation;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return new SizeTransition(
      sizeFactor: new CurvedAnimation(parent: animation, curve: Curves.easeOut),
      axisAlignment: 0.0,
      child: new Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
        child: new Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.0),
              child: snapshot.value['photoURl'] == null
                  ? new CircleAvatar()
                  : new CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage: new NetworkImage(snapshot.value['photoURl']),
              ),
            ),
            new Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Text(snapshot.value['displayName'],
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subhead),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Followers, referencing Users.]

Comment: This is a good answer, but I would use `StreamBuilder` and `onValue` instead of `FutureBuilder` and `once()`