# How can I get documents from firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get documents from Firebase but when I print the document it says 0. So that means there's no document, but it is actually.
Here how I'm trying it

```
  Icon custIcon = Icon(Icons.search);
  Widget cusSearchBar = Text("Meine Freunde");
 Future myVideos;
  int likes = 0;
  int videos = 0;
  int followers;
  int following;
  bool dataisthere = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return getBody(context);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getalldata();
  }

  getalldata() async {
    String myID = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid;
    //get videos as future
    var uid = 'Fp3unLwcl2SGVh4MbUPiRVAylYV2';
   var  idofotheruser= await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('meinprofilsettings').doc(myID).collection('following').id.length;
    myVideos =  FirebaseFirestore.instance
       .collection('videos')
        .where('uid', isEqualTo:idofotheruser)
        .get();

    var documents = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('videos')
        .where('uid', isEqualTo: idofotheruser).get();
        print(documents.docs.length);

        if (!mounted) return;
    setState(() {
      videos = documents.docs.length;
    });
    for (var item in documents.docs) {
      likes = item.data()['likes'].length + likes;
    }
    var followersdocuments = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("meinprofilsettings")
        .doc(myID)
        .collection('followers')
        .get();
    var followingdocuments = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("meinprofilsettings")
        .doc(myID)
        .collection('following')
        .get();
    followers = followersdocuments.docs.length;
    following = followingdocuments.docs.length;

    setState(() {
      dataisthere = true;
    });
  }

  Widget getBody(BuildContext context) {
    return dataisthere == false
        ? Scaffold(body: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()))
        : Stack(children: <Widget>[
            Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                 actions: [
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                    onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context)
                          .pushNamed(Searchuserinmeinebeitraege.route);
                    },
                  ),
                  
                ],

                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                elevation: 0.0,
              ),
              body: RefreshIndicator(
                onRefresh: _handleRefresh,
                color: Colors.black,
                strokeWidth: 4,
                child: ListView(
                  children: [
                    Column(children: <Widget>[
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 5,
                      ),
                      FutureBuilder(
                          future: myVideos,
                          builder: (context, snapshot) {
                            if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                                ConnectionState.waiting) {
                              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                            }
                            if (videos > 0) {
                              return StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
                                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                                crossAxisCount: 3,
                                itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                  DocumentSnapshot video =
                                      snapshot.data.docs[index];
                                  return InkWell(
                                    onTap: () {
                                      NavigationService.instance
                                          .navigateToRoute(MaterialPageRoute(
                                              builder: (context) {
                                        return VideoPage(
                                          video.data()['videourl'],
                                          video.data()['uid'],
                                          video.id,
                                        );
                                      }));
                                    },
                                    child: Card(
                                      elevation: 0.0,
                                      child: ClipRRect(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                                        clipBehavior:
                                            Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
                                        child: Image.network(
                                          video.data()['previewimage'],
                                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                        ),
                                      ),

                                      //imageData: searchImages[index],
                                    ),
                                  );
                                },
                                staggeredTileBuilder: (index) =>
                                    StaggeredTile.count(
                                        (index % 7 == 0) ? 2 : 1,
                                        (index % 7 == 0) ? 2 : 1),
                                mainAxisSpacing: 8.0,
                                crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
                              );
                            } else

                              //picturesdontexists = true)
                              return Center(
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding:
                                      const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 100, 0, 0),
                                  child: Container(
                                    child: Text(
                                      "No Videos Yet",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 18, color: Colors.black),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                          }),
                    ]),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ]);
  }
```

And here is my Firebase
[image][image]

[image]

So what I'm trying to get all videos of the user that I follow. The `uid` in videos collection should be equal to the `uid` of a user that I  follow user

Answer (score 1):

This problem is in this fragment of your code:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('meinprofilsettings').doc(myID).collection('following').id
```

This is a very long-winded way to say `'following'`. It does *not* read anything from the database, which is probably what you want to do.

Keep in mind that Firestore does not perform any type of server-side join when reading data. If you want to compare to a specific value in your query, you will have to provide that specific value in the code:

```
var uid = 'Fp3unLwcl2SGVh4MbUPiRVAylYV2';
FirebaseFirestore.instance
       .collection('videos')
       .where('uid', isEqualTo: uid)
       ...
```

So you'll need to determine the UID in a separate step, and then provide that value to the video query.

Comment: I think this is going to turn out like the question you answered a few mins ago, where the video doc will need an array of ids of users who are following.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/67149604/294949

Comment: I think you not understand I dont want only the document of one user I want all documents videos from that users that I follow . That what you doing is hardcoding one uid

Comment: The process is the same for multiple users. You'll need to create a list of the IDs for those users, and then load each of their docs separate - or in batches of up to 10 with `in`: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any

Comment: Agree about the pedagogy @FrankvanPuffelen.  Agree about the votes, and I'll donate a few bucks to Bill Gates, also :-) (and I understand that's a poor analogy)

Comment: Hmm do you have an example for your idea with the load each of their docs separate maybe a code because im not really understand how to do that ?

Comment: following is a collection an and the ids inside following are documents arent they? So can i not using the dochment as a list what you said ? Please give me an code example im really not unterstand what you mean

Comment: Here are some good reference questions of showing data from two collections: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59061225/how-do-i-join-data-from-two-firestore-collections-in-flutter, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54650261/firestore-replicating-a-sql-join-for-nosql-and-flutter, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44185979/flutter-firebase-database-joining-two-nodes, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52865578/how-to-inner-join-in-firestore

Comment: Please check my code so you can see what im trying and maybe explaining what I should do . So I have to wrap ,the howle widget with a streambuilder if I understand it correctly in this streambuilder I should get a list of all following datas and then ? How do I get access to all videos of the person that I following ?????